# mdadm - exclude drive from monitor

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have created a RAID 1 array with a single drive (in order to add a second drive later).

`# mdadm --create /dev/md5 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 missing`

But, I execute `/sbin/mdadm --monitor --scan --oneshot`, it sends me a `DegradedArray event` e-mail.

Even if this is true, I would like to know if it's possible to exclude `/dev/md5` from this check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible - in a manner of speaking, just for RAID1. Change it to one drive.

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md5 --raid-devices=1 --force
```

It should then show up as being in a good state:

```
md0 : active raid1 sdx1[42]
      12345678 blocks super 1.2 [1/1] [U]
```

With this there is no longer a missing drive and `mdadm` should no longer complain about it being degraded.

When you are ready to add your second drive later, just grow it again:

```
mdadm --grow /dev/md5 --raid-devices=2 --force
mdadm --manage /dev/md5 --add /dev/sdy1
```

I use this to make a bootable mirror of my single SSD to HDD from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Peeking at the source code, if you use the `--scan` command line switch, `mdadm` parses `/proc/mdstat` without any kind of filtering in place. And if you don't use `--scan`, you have to supply a device name, which defeats your purpose.